Changing theme using react-navigation/native ThemeProvider
I am using the react-navigation/native ThemeProvider for managing the theme in my react-native expo app. While setting the theme to the devices default worked out of the box, I am having trouble setting the theme manually in my app via some kind of theme toggle. The documentation does not provide any details on how to set the theme manually.
This is how I use the ThemeProvider in my root layout:
<ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
This is my useThemeColor hook:
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";

export function useThemeColor(
  props: { light?: string; dark?: string },
  colorName: keyof typeof Colors.light & keyof typeof Colors.dark
) {
  const theme = useColorScheme() ?? "light";
  const colorFromProps = props[theme];

  if (colorFromProps) {
    return colorFromProps;
  } else {
    return Colors[theme][colorName];
  }
}


And this is a custom component that I use:
import { View, type ViewProps } from "react-native";

import { useThemeColor } from "@/hooks/useThemeColor";

export type ThemedViewProps = ViewProps & {
  lightColor?: string;
  darkColor?: string;
};

export function ThemedView({
  style,
  lightColor,
  darkColor,
  ...otherProps
}: ThemedViewProps) {
  const backgroundColor = useThemeColor(
    { light: lightColor, dark: darkColor },
    "background"
  );

  return <View style={[{ backgroundColor }, style]} {...otherProps} />;
}


I looked at various post on this platform but could not find one that actually uses the ThemeProvider from react-navigation/native.
